# How to Access SchedulerRegistery ID in Nest Js

Tags: cron, nestjs

I am using `@nestjs/schedule` for scheduling tasks. Sample code for scheduling are as follows

```
 async scheduleCron(cronId: any, day: any){
        let cronTime = '0 0 '+day+' * *';
       
        const job = new CronJob('* * * * *', () => {
          this.postOrder();
        });
        this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob(cronId, job);
        job.start();

      }
```

Here `cronId` is my custom Id which I passed to identify between different crons. Now when postOrder is called by a specific cronjob I want to access cronId of cronjob so that I know which cronjob had executed and based on that I can make appropriate db queries.

Is there a way I can access id ?.
From [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#dynamic-schedule-module-api) what I understand is that you need to pass id to fetch details and not the other way around.

Any clue or alternative way to solve this issue would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean accessing the list of the job like this?

```
this.schedulerRegistry.getCronJobs().forEach((job) => {
    job.stop();
  })
```